How do I disable lights by default when I create a new later in grease pencil?
New layers always have "Lights" checked. I have to go through each layer and uncheck it, which is annoying and time-consuming. Is there a way to disable this by default?



Go to the Object tab and in the Visibility section you can disable lights for the entire objects. Layers will still have the Use Lights checkbox enabled but they will not react to your scene lighting.

(as pointed out in a comment to this question)

That helps a lot, thanks. But now my new problem is I have to turn lights off for every new object. Is there a way to turn lights of entirely so I never even have to think about them? I never use them.

hmm, i don't think that's doable, but it would be worth posting as a feature request on right click select as I would totally use it. Also, if this answer is helpful you can up-vote it without accepting it, thanks

done it: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/GYO8/
